# Check whether the functions are commutative or not

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$$f:R → R$$
$$g:R → R$$
$$f(x) = 2x $$
and
$$g(x) = 3x^2-1$$
Check whether the functions are commutative or not i.e.
$$f\circ g=g\circ f$$

Comment: Or better, "Check whether the functions are commutative or not." What have you tried?

Comment: @BrianO I have tried same as in Answer but I was confused due to domain and ranges?

Comment: My answer or hint would have been: figure out $g(f(x))$ by substituting $f(x) = 2x$ into $g(y) = 3y^2-1$ ; figure out $f(g(x))$ by substituting $g(x) = 3x^2-1$ into $f(y)=2y$; compare the results.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks. I have solved it.

Comment: You're welcome. Did the change of variables (using both $y$ and $x$) help?

Answer (score 2):

Since $2(3x^2-1) \neq 3(2x)^2-1$ for all values of $x$ this cannot be commutative under composition.

Comment: under composition mean?

Comment: "under composition" refers to composition as an operation on functions, in the same way that we have the operation of multiplication on integers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative because we have $$f\circ g(x) = f(3x^2-1) = 2(3x^2-1)$$ and $$g\circ f(x) = g(2x) = 3(2x)^2-1.$$